# How to pass data from an axios API inside a state using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an api (an arr of objects) which I need to pass into a state, so that I can then pass that data inside a component to show it on the website.

1st approach:

```
    // pulls the api data
    const newData = axios.get(url).then((resp) => {
        const apiData = resp.data;

        apiData.map((video) => {
            return video;
        });
    });

    // sets the state for the video
    const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(newData[0]);
    const [videos] = useState(videoDetailsData);

    ...

    return (
        <>
            <FeaturedVideoDescription selectedVideo={selectedVideo} />
        </>
    )
```

2nd approach:

```
    const useAxiosUrl = () => {
        const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(null);

        useEffect(() => {
            axios
            .get(url)
            .then((resp) => setSelectedVideo(resp.data))
        });
        return selectedVideo;
    }

    ...

    return (
        <>
            <FeaturedVideoDescription selectedVideo={selectedVideo} />
        </>
    )
```

both of these approaches don't seem to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: have u tried to initialise useState outside const? its weird useEffect is inside as well, it should be brought outside the const fn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to call your axios method inside the `useEffect` function.

```
const fetchData = axios.get(url).then((resp) => setSelectedVideo(resp.data)));

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [])
```

or if you need `async/await`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    setSelectedVideo(resp.data);
  }
    
  fetchData();
}, [])
```